# Trying to add an event lister to js file

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am just trying to set up a simple `addEventListener` but it is giving me type `error`.

I've tried switching the order of my js but nothing seems to work.

```
// my script

const serviceContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("serviceImg-container");

serviceContainer.addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert("Hellooo worlddd!!");
});
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will target a nodeList with the class ´serviceImg-container`, then u should iterate each item of the nodeList with his listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer working with id's makes it easier because there can only be one Id.

```html
<div id='serviceImg-container'><img src='someimage.com'/></div>
```

```js
document.querySelector('#serviceImg-container').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert('hello world!');
}
```

Comment: It worked dude. Thank you!! I wanted to put the ID in a variable and then use the event listener method on that ID. But either way,  you helped a bunch. Thanks!